# Excel 2016- Load power query directly into power pivot

Tags: powerpivot, powerquery

Is there a way to load power query data directly into power pivot without creating an excel table as an intermediary step?

All the examples I've found reference Excel 2010 and 2013. Although the instructions are similar, it does not work in 2016.

In following the steps found. when I go to "Existing Connections" in Power Pivot and try to open the Power Query connection. I get a message:

"The connection you’re trying to open was created with Power Query. To change this connection, use Power Query."

Is it possible to clean/transform data using power query and load it directly to power pivot in excel 2016?

Comment: The message you get doesn't mean that an Excel table was created as an intermediate step. It just tells you that the connection was created with Power Query (and loaded directly into your data model).

Comment: but I still cannot load the data into Powerpivot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go to the Data Ribbon and choose **Show Queries**. Depending on your Office/Excel update schedule, this may be changed to **Queries & Connections**.  Either way, you are trying to open the **Workbook Queries** pane (appears on the right).

Within the **Workbook Queries** pane, right-click each Query and choose Load To.  Ensure the first option is set to **Only Create Connection**, and that the **Add this data to the Data Model** option is checked.

With those options set, Load performance should be a lot faster, and you can exceed Excel's million row per table limit.

Comment: strangely, when I tried this on my home computer it works, but on my work machine the data does not appear in Powerpivot. Can you think of why this is happening?

Comment: Different versions of Excel perhaps?  I recall this being very flaky back in the 2010 version.  Note you need to compare build numbers these days as Excel is a moving target.

Answer (score 2):

On the Excel Workbook Ribbon:

### Option 1:

Go to: Power Pivot ↦ Add To Data Model

[image]

### Option 2:

1. Go to Data ↦ Queries & Connections

[image]

2. <kbd>right-click</kbd> over the query you want to add to PowerPivot ↦ Edit

[image]

3. On the Power Query Editor: File ↦ Options & Settings ↦ Query Options ↦ Check Load to Data Model.

[image]

4. Finally: File ↦ Close & Load